# Is is possible to use the CASE statement within the WHERE CLAUSE in this format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written an SQL query that will return a set of results but the result set that has been returned is not precise enough! So what I am trying to do now is to trim the result set down to get the exact information that I require! Each Item that I want is coming back with multiple rows and I am looking for a particular row to return to the user.

So I want to search for a value within my where clause and only select the desired criteria from that item! I have written this case statement within my where clause but I can't get it to function effectively:

```
and SourceType.Name = (CASE When SourceType.Name = '7550RTU' Then 
                        Select Quantity.Name from Quantity
                        Where Quantity.Name = 'DI-S1 Cnt'
                    End)
```

Comment: Try it and you will see that it is possible.

Comment: It won't work and thats why I am asking the question, need to find out if its possible now!

Comment: You need to give details about what you want and what you tried.

Comment: Case EXPRESSION, not case statement... The case statement is a stored procedure construction. BTW, make sure your sub-select never returns mote than 1 row!

Comment: `need to find out if its possible now!` Comments like this are not very constructive, nor do they inspire to help. What is your `--Select Statement--`?

Comment: I will get you the select statement now and edit the question

Comment: The question has been edited, hope this makes the problem clearer

Answer (score 1):

```
and SourceType.Name = (CASE When SourceType.Name = '7550RTU' Then 
                        (Select Quantity.Name from Quantity
                         Where Quantity.Name = 'DI-S1 Cnt')
                    End)
```

I.e. put the sub-query between parentheses. (Remember, sub-query should never return more than one row here.)

But if you watch more closely you'll find some logical issues.

The sub-select `(Select Quantity.Name from Quantity Where Quantity.Name = 'DI-S1 Cnt')` will either return the value 'DI-S1 Cnt' or NULL (if no such row exists).

This means that the CASE returns either 'DI-S1 Cnt' (if SourceType.Name = '7550RTU' and sub-select row exists), or NULL (if and SourceType.Name<> '7550RTU' or no sub-select row exists.)

If SourceType.Name is '7550RTU', and the CASE returns 'DI-S1 Cnt', the comparison is FALSE. If SourceType.Name is '7550RTU' and the CASE returns NULL, the comparison is unknown/NULL. If  SourceType.Name is not '7550RTU', the comparison is FALSE (or NULL.)

So the main question is, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Is there a way that it could return more that 1 row? or is there another procedure for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is if that subquery will return more than  1 row you can select top 1 record from your select top1 data list returned from your query